# Is it possible to upload a template file to a directory that can be used by all themes?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, page-template

I have a custom php file that I want to use as a template (i.e. selecting it from the "Template" dropdown in the image below).

Right now, I have to identify which theme I am using and place the template file in the *theme folder*.

Is there a place in my filesystem where I can place the template file so it can be used by whichever theme I decide to use later?

[image]

Comment: Doing a quick search got me tutorials like [this one](https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/). Have you seen/tried those methods already?

Answer (score 5):

No, WordPress has no default place in its system where it will look for templates outside the current theme folder.

That said, you can easily [build a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that inserts a template into the system. You can use the [`theme_page_templates`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) to insert a template name in the dropdown list. Then you hook into [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) and depending on whether [`get_page_template_slug`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/) return your template's slug you divert the template to the one in your plugin-directory.

Comment: Сould you add a simple example for the `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` ?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I included the wrong filter, it should've been `theme_page_templates`. There is an example in the link.